# Sincronizar SQLServer Express 2014 com SQLServer LocalDB usando C#

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-localdb, sql-server-express

Estou a fazer uma aplicação `Windows Forms` usando `C#` que estará ligada a um banco `SqlServer Express 2014` remoto, porém, necessito que algumas funcionalidades estejam disponíveis `offline` devido a má qualidade da `internet`.

Como poderia fazer `sincronização` bidirecional do banco remoto com um banco `SQLServer LocalDB` para que o banco remoto possa estar atualizado com as informações inseridas no `SQLServer LocalDB`?

Comment: Já pensou em criar um pacote SSIS?

Comment: Você pode usar o [Sync Framework](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2190.tutorial-synchronizing-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact-sync-framework.aspx)?